# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, soap-client

I am trying to access WSDL using PHP SOAP. WSDL URL is http://vmwin888.ddns.net:8080/GameLobbyWS/GameLobbyWS.svc?wsdl
It is working fine if we open through browser, but gives error when try to access through PHP SOAP.

I am getting this error...

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://vmwin888.ddns.net:8080/GameLobbyWS/GameLobbyWS.svc?wsdl' :
>   Start tag expected, '<' not found

**PHP code :**

```
$reqDT = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$signature = md5("abcdefg"."GetGameList".$reqDT."123456");
$soap_client = new SoapClient("http://vmwin888.ddns.net:8080/GameLobbyWS/GameLobbyWS.svc?wsdl");
$info = new StdClass();
$info->key = "OperatorID";
$info->value = "abcdefg";
$info->key = "OperatorPassword";
$info->value = "123456";
$info->key = "RequestDateTime";
$info->value = $reqDT;
$info->key = "Signature";
$info->value = $signature;
$param = array($info);
$result = $soap_client->__soapCall('GetGameList',$param);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: add your php code in question

Comment: It is not working using file_get_contents as well.